# How to map Promise<T> to Guarantee<Bool>?

Tags: ios, promisekit

I have a `Promise<T>` that I would like to transform into a `Guarantee<Bool>` where true means the promise fulfilled and false if it got rejected.

I managed to reach this using

```
  return getPromise()
    .map { _ in true }
    .recover { _ in Guarantee.value(false) }
```

I'm wondering if there is a neater way to do this.

Comment: You can pass bool value inside of promise ?

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the original code and the answers here, I would make the extension explicitly for `Void` Promises, and keep the naming more inline with PromiseKit:

```
extension Promise where T == Void {
    func asGuarantee() -> Guarantee<Bool> {
        self.map { true }.recover { _ in .value(false) }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `promise` as below for easy usage mentioned under **Usage**

```
extension Promise {

    func guarantee() -> Guarantee<Bool> {
        return Guarantee<Bool>(resolver: { [weak self] (body) in
            self?.done({ (result) in
                body(true)
            }).catch({ (error) in
                body(false)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
// If you want to execute a single promise and care about success only.
getPromise().guarantee().done { response in
    // Promise success handling here.
}

// For chaining multiple promises
getPromise().guarantee().then { bool -> Promise<Int> in
        return .value(20)
    }.then { integer -> Promise<String> in
        return .value("Kamran")
    }.done { name in
        print(name)
    }.catch { e in
        print(e)
}
```